# How to use snd-aloop correctly?

Tags: sound, alsa

I wanted an output-to-input loopback device for recording system audio so I ran:

```
modprobe snd-aloop
```

This worked insofar as it created a virtual device and all my system audio output automatically switched to this device. It also created a matching input device but it seems no audio is coming into that input device even when the corresponding output is receiving audio. I'm wondering what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It seems as though snd-aloop has some issues but on my machine (a raspberry pi 4 running rasbian os) i have fixed it by
running

> sudo bash |
> sudo echo 'snd-aloop' >> /etc/modules |
> exit

this seems to somehow direct the output to the virtual input device.

i think that **modprobe snd-aloop** just creates the loopback devices but the command **sudo echo 'snd-aloop' >> /etc/modules** appears to create and direct it to the correct devices.

hope this helps.